# PHP & MS Access 2007 on Shared Linux Hosting

Tags: php, ms-access-2007, shared-hosting

Basically I work for a dining services company that has a menu database that we use for each week at multiple locations stored in a Microsoft Access 2007 .accdb file. I'm trying to develop a PHP application on shared hosting so that the .accdb file can be uploaded and queried as to generate and store HTML menus for the week based on the database.

Million dollar question: how can I interact with this .accdb file form within PHP on shared hosting? I guess I just kind of assumed Zend or Pear would have a driver for me when I started off, but I'm having some trouble finding anything of substance, especially for shared hosting.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm an old Access hand and I wouldn't use ACCDB at all -- I'd upload data into a proper database that is designed to function well as back end to a website, e.g., SQL Server or MySQL or PostgreSQL. Only Windows-based hosting will likely be able to use an ACCDB, and many of those will only support MDBs. But that's not advisable, as Jet/ACE is not threadsafe and isn't going to function well as the back end of a website (though since it's read-only, you'd be avoiding most of the problems that come with that).

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody, what I've decided to do is write a windows GUI app in C#. I chose this route because accessing the access DB locally would be faster and more reliable, and the parsed information still has to be uploaded to a third party website via http POST requests. So far it's going pretty well, on the database side, I just need to work my way around writing the http client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this question:
[database connection in php with MS Access on linux hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278970/database-connection-in-php-with-ms-access-on-linux-hosting/)

Most people (including me :) ) are recommending migrating the Access database to MySQL (or Postgres), and running that as the live database on the website.  If there are people/processes in your office that rely on Access, you can use Access as a frontend by connecting it to the live MySQL database [over ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

This may be of interest: http://bryanmills.net/archives/2003/11/microsoft-access-database-using-linux-and-php/

via [database connection in php with MS Access on linux hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278970/database-connection-in-php-with-ms-access-on-linux-hosting)

Comment: Thanks, I saw this page via the same SO question. However it isn't very helpful for a shared hosting situation where I can't install RPMs, and also it doesn't mention anything about Access 2007 compatibility.

Thanks for the reply though, appreciate it.

Comment: In case someone looking for this Answer, the website link `bryanmilla` is down

Comment: @AdarshMadrecha try https://web.archive.org/web/20081120204521/http://bryanmills.net/archives/2003/11/microsoft-access-database-using-linux-and-php/